# Get url from response with guzzle is not working

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

This code below:

```
$url = json_decode($getClient->getBody()->getContents());
dd($url);
```

shows:

```
{#302 ▼
  +"output": {#304 ▼
    +"url": "https://...▶"
  }
}
```

I want to store the url in a variable, but with `$urlLink = $url['url'];` it shows the error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

But with `$urlLink = $url->url;` shows also an error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$url
```

Do you know why?

Comment: `$url->output->url`?

Comment: Thanks, like that appears at first "Trying to get property of non-object". But then it shows the url. But at first shows always that error.

Comment: In the API says that to download the file is an asynchronous operation, which means that the file may not be ready immediately. Maybe is because of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because **url** is inside the `output` object.

```
$response = $getClient->getBody()->getContents();

$url = null;
if(!empty($response)) {
  $response = json_decode($response);

  $url = !empty($response->output->url) ?: $response->output->url : '';
}

// Handle the redirection this way.
// If $url == null then that means no response from API.
// If $url == '' then the file hasn't been completely uploaded.
```

This is how it should be done.

Comment: Thanks, like that appears at first "Trying to get property of non-object". But then if the page is acessed again it shows the url. But at first shows always that error. In the API says that to download the file is an asynchronous operation, which means that the file may not be ready immediately. I dont know if the issue can be because of that.

Comment: @John What do you mean by it shows first? The API response changes after the file has completely been uploaded?

Comment: When the page is first acessed the dd($url) shows that error, but if the page is acessed again the error dont shows and the url link appears on the page.

Comment: For example after that code "  $url = null;
        if(!empty($response)) {
            $response = json_decode($response);

            $url = $response->output->pdfUrl;
        }" I put         header("Location: $url");. But when the user acesses the page at first it appears "Trying to get property of non-object
" but if the user click in the browser refresh button the file is downloaded.

Comment: It seems that for the file be generated is necessary send two requests and in the first appears "Trying to get property of non-object
". In the second the file is transfered, in the third it appears again "Trying to get property of non-object
".

Comment: @John Updated my answer. Use `redirect()` function for redirecting the user rather than `header(Location: $url)`..... :)

Comment: @John I don't know how your rest of the code works. Bust honestly, just check response... If it's empty, if it's not etc. and handle the redirection that way. :)

Comment: Thanks, like that at first it appears a blank page, then when the user refreshes the page the file is downloaded. Do you know what is necessary for the user only click once in the button to download the file?

Comment: @John You mean how to ensure user only clicks one time?

Comment: The user do only one request for the file be downloaded instead of necessary two requests.